# Unable to find the war file but exit in target folder

Tags: jenkins, nexus, artifact

As i am building the file and uploading it to nexus repository. In the way i can build the file and the war file is present in target folder (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/orders-2.0.0.war) But while Uploading war file to nexus i am getting an error saying "order-2.0.0.war file doesn't exist. find the below console output and Jenkinsfile and help me with a solution.

```html
+ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< in.javahome:orders >-------------------------
[INFO] Building orders 2.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ orders ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ orders ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ orders ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ orders ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ orders ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ orders ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running in.javahome.orders.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec - in in.javahome.orders.AppTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ orders ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [orders] in [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/orders-2.0.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [128 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/orders-2.0.0.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ orders ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.936 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-09T07:37:04Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (upload artifacts)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readMavenPom
[Pipeline] nexusArtifactUploader
order-2.0.0.war file doesn't exist
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
java.io.IOException: order-2.0.0.war file doesn't exist
    at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution$1.call(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:267)
    at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution$1.call(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:256)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1163)
    at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution.run(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:256)
    at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution.run(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:217)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:367)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

```html
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools{
        maven 'maven3'
    }
     stages{
           stage('Build'){
               steps{
                  sh 'mvn clean package'
               }
           }
          stage('upload artifacts'){
              steps{
                  script{

                    def mavenPom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
                      nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: 
                      [
                          [
                              artifactId: 'orders', 
                              classifier: '', 
                              file: "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Declerative_pipeline/target/order-${mavenPom.version}.war", 
                              type: 'war'
                          ]
                      ], 
                      credentialsId: 'Nexusnir', 
                      groupId: 'in.javahome', 
                      nexusUrl: '13.232.6.115:8081', 
                      nexusVersion: 'nexus3', 
                      protocol: 'http', 
                      repository: 'Declarative_Pipeline', 
                      version: "${mavenPom.version}"
                  }
              }
          }
    }
}
```